# Replace nth-occurence of a string with an html tag

Tags: javascript, replace, tags

I am trying to replace the second / of the following string with a 
 tag so that the year will break line

`<span class="post-date">15/03/2024</span>`

Is there any way to replace a character(or string in general) with an html tag, like the `<br>` tag?

Comment: I'm sure you know there is a way but the question is what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
 <span class="post-date" id="post-date">15/03/2024</span>

<script>
var dateString = document.getElementById("post-date").innerHTML;
var secondSlashIndex = dateString.indexOf('/', dateString.indexOf('/') + 1);
var firstPart = dateString.substring(0, secondSlashIndex);
var secondPart = dateString.substring(secondSlashIndex + 1);
var replacedString = firstPart + "<br>" + secondPart;
document.getElementById("post-date").innerHTML = replacedString;
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).